# updating page without affecting the process going on

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Hello all have a div1 which contains many other divs2,div3.....
and i want to reload div div1 after every 13 sec but without affecting the process that we are doing on other divs process may be typing messages ,viewing image etc..

can anyone please help me with this..

this is thepiece of code that i have used yet..
the code is working fine it reloads the div1 but every time it loads i need to type the message again if i have not posted it ..and some times it scroll down too..

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#div1').load('home.php #div1').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 13000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments via load, Say draft for not saved and post for saved one. Suppose $('#myContent') contains your post content then the following code can  be used:

```
$("#myDiv").load("home.php?post="+$('#myContent').val())//send posted data
```

OR

```
$("#myDiv").load("home.php?, {draft:$('#myContent').val() })//send draft data
```